# Create new lists from list where each list is 1 element shorter

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] and I want to break it into multiple lists like:
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[1,2,3,4,5,6]...

```
def breakdown(a):
    x = []
    y = []
    q = len(a)
    while q > 0:
        y += [a]
        a.pop()
        q -= 1
    print(y)
```

The above code returns empty lists, and if I remove the brackets from y+=[a], I'll get a list of the correct elements ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6....], but not broken down into separate lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate issue is that `y += [a]` *extends* `y` (it actually creates a new list but conceptually it extends `y`) when you want to *append* onto `y`.  We can simply patch your code:

```
def breakdown(a):
    y = []
    q = len(a)

    while q > 0:
        y += [list(a)]
        a.pop()
        q -= 1

    return y

my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

my_lists = breakdown(my_list)

print(my_lists)
```

OUTPUT

```
% python3 test.py
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1]]
%
```

But a cleaner approach might be to use `.append()` directly:

```
def breakdown(a):
    y = []
    q = len(a)

    while q > 0:
        y.append(a[0:q])
        q -= 1

    return y
```

And of course, we could convert this to the obligatory list comprehension:

```
my_lists = [my_list[0:i] for i in range(len(my_list), 0, -1)]
```

But an explicit function like you're using is just fine.

Comment: I've been trying to improve my list comprehension, so I'm stoked you included that. Thank you so much for the help. I knew I was making a dumb mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehensions

```
>>> a = [list(range(1,i+1)) for i in range(8,0,-1)]
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1]]
```

Edit : My bad, I understood the problem wrong. You can use the slicing technique to solve it

```
def breakdown(li):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(li)-1, -1, -1):
        result.append(li[:i+1])
    return result

a = [3, 7, 1, 5, 4, 2, 8, 6]
my_lists = breakdown(a)
print(my_lists)

a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
my_lists = breakdown(a)
print(my_lists)
```

Comment: The OP said they had a list, not a number.  The question would have been equally valid if the example list was ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'] or [3, 7, 1, 5, 4, 2, 8, 6] but your answer would not be.  You assumption about the data may be correct, but it's clearly an (unstated) assumption.

Comment: my bad @cdlane changing it now